# What are state variables in joomla

Tags: joomla

What is the usage of state variables in Joomla? and what is the usage of `$model->setState` in this code (the code is from Joomla's mod_articles_popular module)?

```
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
// Set application parameters in model
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$appParams = $app->getParams();
$model->setState('params', $appParams); 
// Set the filters based on the module params
$model->setState('list.start', 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState method to a model used to filter data , you can read the details on [here](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:How_to_add_custom_filters_to_components). and function syntax and param list can be [here](https://docs.joomla.org/API15:JModel/setState).

the main purpose of this method is to filter the result set using parameters. in your case its module param an example post can be found [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=578&t=521308).

Hope it clear now.